# Значение приставки "обер" в слове "обер-офицер"

Tags: приставка, значение

Благородие - титулование обер-офицерских чинов. Приставка "обер-" имеет значение "высший": обер-мастер - наилучший мастер. Отчего же обер-офицерские чины представляют самые низкие в табели о рангах чины?

Comment: А вы бы привели этот самый табель о рангах, на который ссылаетесь.

Comment: Это вопрос по русскому языку?!

Comment: По русскому. Ведь выясняется значение слова, уточняется значение расхожей приставки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, обер-офицеры противопославлялись унтер-офицерам, занимавшим в армейской иерархии самое низшее положение (сразу после рядовых).

В категорию унтер-офицеров попадали урядники, прапорщики, капралы, сержанты. Следующий над ними уровень и был обер-офицерским.